# npm error 404 not found

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm trying to install a npm package using:

```
npm install microsoft-speech-browser-SDK
```

I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: microsoft-speech-browser-SDK@latest
```

I have also tried setting the registry using both:

```
npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: It's microsoft-speech-browser-sdk, with lower case sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NPM is case-sensitive, you need to use a lowercase "SDK": `npm install microsoft-speech-browser-sdk`.

[NPM Issue #3914](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3914) provides more information on why.

Comment: I noticed that :). You can submit a PR or issue on their GitHub page.

Answer (score 3):

The name is case-sensitive [`microsoft-speech-browser-sdk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-speech-browser-sdk), so try:

```
npm i microsoft-speech-browser-sdk
```